# Perturbation of roots on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the following lemma right? I think there are some errors in the proof.

Lemma) If $r$ is a root of $\phi(z)$ on the unit circle of multiplicity $m$, then the polynomial $\phi^\epsilon(z):=\phi(z)+\epsilon z \phi'(z)$ has a root satisfying $$r^\epsilon:= r(1+\epsilon)^{-m}+O(\epsilon^2)$$

Proof) $\phi^\epsilon(r(1+\delta))=\phi(r(1+\delta))+\epsilon r(1+\delta)   \phi'(r(1+\delta))
\\ = \frac 1 {m!} \phi^{(m)}(r)(r\delta)^m+\epsilon r (1+\delta) \frac 1 {(m-1)!} \phi^{(m)} (r) (r\delta)^{m-1} + O(\delta^{m+1})
\\ = \frac 1 {m!} \phi^{(m)}(r)r^m\delta^{m-1} (\delta + m \epsilon + O(\delta^2)) $

Hence $\delta = -m \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)$ and $r^\epsilon = r(1+\delta)=r(1-m \epsilon) + O(\epsilon^2)= r(1+ \epsilon)^{-m} + O(\epsilon^2)$

I cannot understand line 2,3,4 of the proof, unless $\epsilon = O(\delta), \delta=O(\epsilon)$. But is it true?

Comment: Either, a bad idea note $\epsilon$ for an integer or $\phi^\epsilon(z)$ is not a polynomial. Is it an index notation?

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez Yes, it is an index.